# WPF Mysql Data too long for column

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, insert

I am getting an error that i dont understand. I have a form where a new row has to be added when i press the button add. It has to check for the values in comboBox cb_Character and from comboBox cb_Talents. When i test it i get the error. Data too Long for column, however when i try it in Mysql i am able to do it. what is wrong?

```
 private void btn_addTalent_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string constring = "datasource= localhost; port=3306; username=root; password=Lorena89;";
            string Query = "SET foreign_key_checks = 0; INSERT INTO dark_heresy.learned_talents (Character_Name, Talent_Name) VALUES ('" + cb_Character + "','" + cb_Talents + "'); SET foreign_key_checks = 1; ";
            MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
            MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand(Query, conDataBase);
            MySqlDataReader myReader;
            try
            {
                conDataBase.Open();
                myReader = cmdDatabase.ExecuteReader();
                MessageBox.Show("Added Talent to Character");
                while (myReader.Read())
                {

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: \r\n" + ex);

            }     

        }
```

Comment: Seems you are passing a reference of the ComboBox `cb_Character` and not its value to the query.

Comment: So far i have used that method to check for values that are in the comboboxes, but yes something must be wrong since it wont do it

Comment: Found the error, i was missing the .TEXT in cb_Character and in cb_Talents

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, i was missing the .Text

```
('" + cb_Character.Text + "','" + cb_Talents.Text + "');
```